# How to get PageLayout Section Lable Name in Salesforce?

Tags: page-layout, inline-visualforce

I am having a Account Page Layout. It is having 4 sections:

MySection (Inline Visualforce Page),
Account Information,
Address Information,
Additional Information

I want get only names of above 4 sections.

So I've written a code, where I'm using Ajax toolkit in script.

```
<script src="../../soap/ajax/19.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also I am using describeLayout() function to get all the page layout details.

But I'm getting only standard Page layout sections name. Not getting my inline visualforce section name.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var output='';

function setupPage() {
 var result;

}

function editLayoutResults(result, obj) {
    output = '';


var allTheLayouts = result.getArray("layouts");
    for (var i = 0; i < allTheLayouts.length; i++){
        var layout = allTheLayouts[i];
        if (layout.editLayoutSections != null){
            var elSections = layout.getArray("editLayoutSections");
            for (var j = 0; j < elSections.length; j++){
                var els = elSections[j];

                output += '\n';
                output += '\n';
                output += els.heading 
                output += '\n';
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Please note that I'm using "editLayoutSections" and "heading" here.

I have taken the reference from [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describelayout_describelayoutresult.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Visualforce elements can't appear on an edit layout at this point, so the section itself will be rendered empty. You need to instead use the `detailLayoutSections` element.

Comment: I have tried with 'detailLayoutSections', still no rsponse for visualforce element.

Comment: The label for the visualforce element will be in a DescribeLayoutComponent; the headers just show the actual labels. Maybe you're not looking at the right data?

Comment: I have tried with DescribeLayoutComponent. It is only giving detail data of standard pagelayout sections, not for Visualforce page.